# How datagrip gets all the documents from a couchbase bucket?

Tags: java, couchbase, sql++, datagrip

Running `GET KEYS FROM BucketName` query on datagrip results with all the keys from the bucket.

However, when querying the same query within the couchbase ui or java sdk results with `syntax error - at KEYS`. How does datagrip be able to get all the documents in the bucket without indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically our JDBC driver detects `GET KEYS FROM BucketName` queries and execute them using `RawManagerRequest` from Couchbase Java SDK. So you cannot run this query in couchbase ui

Here is how we do it: https://github.com/DataGrip/couchbase-jdbc-driver/blob/dev/driver/src/main/java/com/intellij/executor/GetBucketKeysExecutor.java

Answer (score 0):

```
create primary index on bucketname;
SELECT RAW META(b).id FROM bucketname AS b;
```